# cmake: altering the linker command

Tags: linker, cygwin, cmake

This probably very easy when you know how, but I don't :)

I'm trying to build some code that takes uses opengl/glut. I'm using the cygwin version of cmake opengl etc. The only reference I see to opengl/gult is in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLU REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
```

Everything works fine up till the linking stage, which ends with:

```
CMakeFiles/glview.dir/glview.c.o: In function `DrawGLScene': /cygdrive/C/code/libfreenect/examples/glview.c:88: undefined reference to `__imp__glutSwapBuffers@0'
CMakeFiles/glview.dir/glview.c.o: In function `keyPressed': /cygdrive/C/code/libfreenect/examples/glview.c:96: undefined reference to `__imp
etc.
```

After a git of googling I figured out this because cmake is feading the linker a `-lglut` flag, when it should be feading it a `-lgut32` flag. By manually executing the linking command, I can get the program to build:

```
/usr/bin/gcc.exe  -Wall -O3 -g  -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/glview.dir/glview.c.o  -o glview.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libglview.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -L/cygdrive/C/code/libfreenect/lib ../lib/libfreenect.a -lGL -lGLU -lglut32 -lm -lpthread -lusb-1.0
```

But I can't figure out how to get cmake to generate this command for me so no manual steps are needed. Any ideas what I should be doing?

Cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how to add libraries to link to:

```
target_link_libraries( ${TargetName} gut32 )
```

find_package only assures the package is found, no more.

Comment: I think it should be 
target_link_libraries(${TargetName} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} ${GLU_LIBRARIES}  ${OpenGL_LIBRARIES})

Comment: that's surely possible; I guess find_package creates these variables then?

Comment: find_package creates those, yes, if the appropriate libraries are found and it will set these variables to actual lists of required libraries for each component.